# Display loading spinner while filtering data - react-table v7

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-table

Consider this [useFilters Hook example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/filtering) of React Table. Sometimes it may take more than a 1000ms to apply a filter using **setFilter** or **setGlobalFilter**. So how can I display a loading spinner or simply a **loading...** text while data is getting filtered.